# Bandwidth of second-harmonic generated (SHG) field for pulse excitation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

I wanted to know the bandwidth of the second-harmonic field generated from type-I SHG process when excited with a pulse of bandwidth $\Gamma$.

In this lecture notes, the author calculates the acceptance bandwidth of the fundamental pulse for which the phase matching condition satisfies and derives a relationship as a function of crystal length.

http://nicadd.niu.edu/~piot/phys_630/Lesson23.pdf

From his notes, the range of wavelengths (or frequencies) centered around $\lambda$ that achieve approximate phase-matching is given as,

$\delta \lambda = |\frac{0.44 \lambda/L }{(n_z'(\lambda)-0.5 n_z'(\lambda/2))}|$

Following his calculation, with fundamental field $\lambda = 950nm$, I obtain following plot for phase-matching acceptance bandwidth as a function of crystal length[image: crystal length vs acceptance bandwidth]

From the plot, typical acceptance bandwidth for a millimeter crystal which is < 1/10 of a GHz, which seems to be very low. In many experiments, they use picosecond pulses for SHG process which has 100s of GHz bandwidth.

Also the calculation is for acceptance bandwidth but doesn't give the bandwidth of the second-harmonic field. Is the bandwidth of the second-harmonic field comparable to the acceptance bandwidth? In that case the second-harmonic field will be very narrow in frequency.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is it possible you made a calculation error (perhaps wrong units?) while calculating the phase matching bandwidth shown in the plot. Typical PM bandwidths I've encountered for mm-long crystals are at least a few nanometers...

Comment: I just did a quick calculation using the dispersion values at the fundamental and SH wavelengths from [here](http://refractiveindex.info/?shelf=main&book=BaB2O4&page=Eimerl-o) and obtained a value around 10.4 nm for a 1 mm long BBO crystal.